# Yii2 viaTable many-to-many. Tables has no relation. Eagre loading

Tags: php, yii2, many-to-many

There is 2 tables many-to-manty and another Intermediary able

```
$this->createTable('tweet',[
    'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
    'text' => Schema::TYPE_STRING.' NOT NULL',
    'date_written' => Schema::TYPE_STRING.' NOT NULL',
    'date_imported' => Schema::TYPE_STRING.' NOT NULL',
],"ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");
$this->createTable('hashtag',[
    'text' => $this->string(),
    'PRIMARY KEY(text)'
],"ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");
$this->createTable('tweet_hashtag', [
    'tweet_id' => $this->integer(),
    'hashtag_text' => $this->string(),
    'PRIMARY KEY(tweet_id, hashtag_text)'
],"ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

$this->createIndex('idx-tweet_hashtag-tweet_id', 'tweet_hashtag', 'tweet_id');
$this->createIndex('idx-tweet_hashtag-hashtag_text', 'tweet_hashtag', 'hashtag_text');

$this->addForeignKey('fk-tweet_hashtag-tweet_id', 'tweet_hashtag', 'tweet_id', 'tweet', 'id', 'CASCADE');
$this->addForeignKey('fk-tweet_hashtag-hashtag_text', 'tweet_hashtag', 'hashtag_text', 'hashtag', 'text', 'CASCADE');
```

Table Tweet

```
public function getTweetHashtags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TweetHashtag::className(), ['tweet_id' => 'id']);
}
public function getHashtagTexts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Hashtag::className(), ['text' => 'hashtag_text'])->viaTable('tweet_hashtag', ['tweet_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Table tweet_hashtag

```
   public function getHashtagText()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Hashtag::className(), ['text' => 'hashtag_text']);
    }
    public function getTweet()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Tweet::className(), ['id' => 'tweet_id']);
    }
```

Table hashtag

```
    public function getTweetHashtags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TweetHashtag::className(), ['hashtag_text' => 'text']);
    }

    public function getTweets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tweet::className(), ['id' => 'tweet_id'])->viaTable('tweet_hashtag', ['hashtag_text' => 'text']);
    }
```

When i try 
`Tweet::find()->with('hashtag')->where(['id' => $tweetID])->all()`
there is Exception

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'app\models\Tweet has no relation named "hashtag".'
```

How I can correctly made eagre loading. To get 'text' from hashtag table, by id in Tweet table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the name or relation

```
Tweet::find()->with('tweetHashtags')->where(['id' => $tweetID])->all()
```

Comment: Emm... in this case a im get hashtag text from tweet_hashtag tabel.  For this i have `hasMany(TweetHashtag::className(), ['tweet_id' => 'id'])`, but for what i need `hasMany(Hashtag::className(), ['text' => 'hashtag_text'])->viaTable('tweet_hashtag', ['tweet_id' => 'id'])`... sorry but i dont get it(

Comment: Use tweetHastagTexts then  .. My code is a suggestion .. You are using Tweet::find the you can use the relation defined in Tweet model .. if you set a relation that not exists you get the error you showed ..

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I did not understanding that with('relation - not table name')